# Socket.io event listening on a specific room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm not sure it is possible, but I really need that feature.
Can I do something like:

client side

```
sio = io.connect(url);
sio.to('room1').on('update', function(roomName) {
    console.log(roomName);
});
```

Which will be triggered whenever an update event is emitted to 'room1'?

server side:

```
sockets.to('room1').emit('update', 'room1');
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 7):

That, unfortunately, doesn't work just on the client side.
But you can do it on the server side.

Server Setup:

```
sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join', function (room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });
});

//...

sockets.to('room1').emit('update', 'room1');
```

Client:

```
sio.emit('join', 'room1');
sio.on('update', function (room) {
    console.log(room);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, how do I know if 'update' event was activated on 'room1'? My problem arises when a socket is in 2 rooms and needs to distinguish between 'update' on one of those rooms

Answer (score 3):

The "easy" way is to make sure that your emits from the server include the room in the payload.

```
sockets.to(room).emit('update', {room: room, message: 'hello world!'})
```

Most probably you want to do the same on the client-side of things. 
So that the messages sent from the client to the server includes a room identifier so that the message can be routed correctly.

Or you implement name spaces.